# Replacing headlights hb3 12v 60w with hb3 12v 65w

Tags: honda, headlight

I need to replace headlights on my Honda CR-V, currently i have Sylvania hb3 12v 60w 9005 yelowish. Now i what to buy that white one (arround 5000k) and mostly i found Osram and Philips with allmost same specs (hb3 12v 65w 9005) but there is slight difference they are 65w and mine are 60w.

Is that problem?

Thank you :)

Comment: Good question. I hope you swap out all tungsten, and halogen bulbs from the exterior to the interior with LED solutions. Ask more questions, I'll guide you through the process.

Answer (score 1):

No, that small difference is not a problem, but if you wanted to put 100W bulbs then I would be suggesting a relay setup.

Answer (score -1):

Genato, You please avoid those halogen bulbs and upgrade to higher lux, LED solutions. Check these out

[image]

http://m.ebay.com/itm/MOSTPLUS-9005-HB3-H10-LED-headlight-Kit-Cree-60W-7600LM-9140-9145-6000K-Bulb-Set-/331644173681?hash=item4d37887d71%3Ag%3AYRcAAOSw3YJZR3EA&_trkparms=pageci%253Ab04672a7-8603-11e7-b8b0-74dbd1808566%257Cparentrq%253A0216dab815e0abc21f5fe8ddfff90281%257Ciid%253A14

These are marketed as 40 watt per bulb. But actually these are 33 watt each and shoot out 3800 lumens per bulb at 6000K temperature, on top of that these are water proof.

Comment: In my country LED are illegal, to be legal I would need to get approve from police and that's a lot of hasle.

Comment: The LEDs I recommended, have a particular throw of light which in most enclosures will not blind oncoming drivers. It's not a big deal to get a proper written approval from traffic cops in Croatia